# $.mobile.loading refusing not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As the title suggests I'm looking to call the $.mobile.loading method when a user clicks a button to sign them up. Now this has worked a good 50+ times around the website but for some reason the code below doesn't open the $.mobile.loading dialog but it runs the code though. Not to sure why this is happening on this particular situation.

```
<div id ="diaglogfacebookuserdetails" data-role="dialog" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h3 class="headerdialog">Almost Done</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role = "content">
            <center>
            <div class="alert-message info">
                    <div class="box-icon"><img src="css/images/info.svg"></div>
                    <div id="diaglogfacebookuserdetailsmessage"></div>
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="diaglogfacebookuserdetailscell" id="diaglogfacebookuserdetailscell" placeholder="Enter your Cell Number" />

            <select id="diaglogfacebookuserdetailsuni" class = "searchuniversity">
            </select>
            <select name="diaglogfacebookuserdetailscampus" id="diaglogfacebookuserdetailscampus" class = "signupuniversitycampus">
            </select>

            <input type="submit" id ="facebookuserdetailsbutton" name="facebookuserdetailsbutton" value="SUBMIT" data-theme="a"/>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',"#diaglogfacebookuserdetails",

    function(){
    $("#facebookuserdetailsbutton").click(
                function()
                {
                    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
                        text: 'Signing you Up!',
                        textVisible: true,
                        theme: 'a',
                        html: ""
                    });

                    //lots of Code

                   $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you hide the loading dialog right after showing it. Try delaying closing it (as in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/okx1aw1n/)) or hide when data is successfully uploaded to server.

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, 1000);
```